# Evaluate chaiscript file within a chaiscript file

Tags: chaiscript

I'm starting to learn chaiscript and couldn't find this in the documentation.

I know there is API to evaluate a chaiscript file from C++ by calling ChaiScript::eval_file

But is it possible to do the same from a chaiscript file?

Answer (score 4):

From within ChaiScript the `use` function is available, but the `eval_file` is not. `use` only loads a file if it has not already been loaded. `eval_file` loads the file regardless.

```
use("use.inc")

assert_equal("hello", greet())

// Include it a second time and see if there are any errors
use("use.inc")

assert_equal("hello", greet())
```

From here: https://github.com/ChaiScript/ChaiScript/blob/master/unittests/use.chai

Documentation of the C++ implementation of this function is here: http://chaiscript.com/docs/5/classchaiscript_1_1_chai_script.html#a9fc2eaf37274d09d1ee90ffd411e665c

I don't see any documentation specifying that it's also exposed to the ChaiScript runtime, but you can see many of the functions that are exposed here: https://github.com/ChaiScript/ChaiScript/blob/master/include/chaiscript/language/chaiscript_engine.hpp#L318